# How to use loaded data from a csv file in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, svg

H! Guys
First of all, excuse me for my bad english (I'm working on it). Second: I don't know anything about JavaScript and copy this codes piece by peace. So be patient and listen to my situation please.
I have a svg map and when you click on each sectoin, a box will appear and show the region's name and region's evaluation. I already solve the region's name part with:

```
for (var i = 0; i < regions.length; i++){
.... some line codes ....
$infobox.find('.infobox_title').text(this.data('region_name'));
.... some line codes ....
```

Now I want to grab Evaluation's value from a csv file that loads to page using:

```
function loadFile(event) {
 alasql('SELECT * FROM FILE(?,{headers:true})',[event],function(data){
   var myseries = [];
    Object.keys(data[0]).forEach(function(key){
        var ds = data.map(function(d){ return +d[key];});
       myseries.push({name:key,data:ds});
    });
 });
 }
```

I'm sure the data is loaded to page, cuz I checked in console log:

```
console.log(key);
console.log(ds);
```

[image: center]
And my csv file is something like this:
**regions,evaluation

1,90

2,80

...

22,70**
Pleas tell me **How can I grab the evaluation numbers that loaded to the page and replace it in place of "Evaluation's place" ???**
Take a look at snapshot for clearity:
[image: center]

Comment: you have asked the same question under diff name, Im not the one who down voted you but still, play fair :)

Comment: Deleted the previus one, it was very messy.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this code to put labels on top of image.

First, prepare the image with the map in HTML and cover it with container DIV element:

```
<div id="container">
    <img src="map.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;"/>
</div>
```

Then create the new label element, add style properties (position, content, color, etc.) and append it to container on top of it (look at the "position:absolute" style element):

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');

// Create new element dinamically
var lb = document.createElement('div');
lb.innerHTML = '<b>'+d.regionid+'</b><br/>'+d.evaluation;
lb.style.position = "absolute";
lb.style.left = regions[d.regionid-1].x+"px";
lb.style.top = regions[d.regionid-1].y+"px";

// Append new element to container
container.appendChild(lb);
```

See the working snipped below or in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/agershun/rwL2m5yz/2/)

Comments:

1. I did not include the reading CSV code in the example (because you already loaded it).
2. The example does not use d3.js library.

Please, comment if these conditions are important.

```js
var data = [
    {regionid:1,evaluation:90},
    {regionid:2,evaluation:80},
    {regionid:3,evaluation:70},
    {regionid:4,evaluation:60},
    {regionid:5,evaluation:50},
    {regionid:6,evaluation:40},
    {regionid:7,evaluation:30},
];

var regions = [
    {x:110,y:100},
    {x:220,y:100},
    {x:250,y:180},
    {x:250,y:230},
    {x:290,y:220},
    {x:150,y:160},
    {x:350,y:180},
];

var container = document.getElementById('container');

for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    var d = data[i];
    
var lb = document.createElement('div');
lb.innerHTML = '<b>'+d.regionid+'</b><br/>'+d.evaluation;
lb.style.position = "absolute";
lb.style.left = regions[d.regionid-1].x+"px";
lb.style.top = regions[d.regionid-1].y+"px";
lb.style.backgroundColor = "white";
lb.style.textAlign = "center";
container.appendChild(lb);
};
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <img src="https://pbs.twimg.com/media/B8woY_DCMAEojTy.jpg" style="position:absolute; top:0px; left:0px;"/>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, But thats not what I meant. I uploaded my files in a zipped folder, I'll appreciate if you take a look at console log. I want to use the array shown in console inside my codes. I want to replace evaluations with "Evaluation place" (Evaluations inside the csv files that loaded to browser).